# c++0x why are "auto" vars in Range-based for-loop passed to loop body as values, not references?

Tags: foreach, c++11

I had an bug cuz of this, and it made me wonder why it was designed that way.
I feel that it would be better that auto something:container would produce references, not values. 
For eg:

```
int t[3]{11,22,33};
for(int& el:t2)
    el*=2;
```

gives 22,44,66

```
int t[3]{11,22,33};
    for(auto el:t2)
        el*=2;
```

"does nothing".

Comment: so we came to the C++0x rule# 1: don't use `auto` gratuitously.

Comment: @Gene : The problem isn't with `auto`, the problem is with incorrect use of `auto`. That's like saying the problem with `for(int el:t2)` is use of `int`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`auto` in the case you describe deduced that the type was `int`. If you wanted to turn that into a reference you can use `auto&`.

If the C++ compiler would use special rules just because it is in a for loop the rules would extremely confusing.

```
auto i = t[1];
```

is the same as

```
int i = t[1];
```

The same case here, if you want a reference you have to specify that you want a reference.

Comment: Oh, another of those moments... "Oh I see, now it is so obvious that it is the right way to do it". Tnx

Answer (score 4):

`auto` *always* deduces a value type. This is the same mechanism as what happens in a template, such as `template<typename F> void foo(T t)`.

Comment: To be clear, `for(auto& el:t2)` will have the desired behavior.